# Duplicate column name merge in Postgres views

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

In our database we have a a view, which has subselects like `SELECT *, lower(mix_cased_field) AS mix_cased_field`, where `*` already includes a column called `mix_cased_field`.

**My expectation** is that the conflicting columns, i.e. `mix_cased_field`, would be merged and the latter would survive, i.e. I would in my final resultset have only the lowercased field.

**The actual result**, is that in my resultset I have two fields; `mix_cased_field` and `mix_cased_field_1`. When I look at the view's definition in the `pg_views` table, I can see that the latter field has been renamed with the suffix by Postgres, despite my explicit naming of the column.

The query for the view looks roughly like the following:

```sql
-- (table and column names have been renamed to protect the innocent)

SELECT 
  *,
  'TopmostThing' AS __type,
  (
    SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(sub_things), '[]'::jsonb) AS sub_things
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        *,
        'SubThing' AS __type,
        json_date(created_at) AS created_at,
        lower(mix_cased_field) AS mix_cased_field,
        (
          SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(yet_more_things), '[]'::jsonb) AS yet_more_things
          FROM (
            SELECT
              *,
              'YetMoreThing' AS __type,
              lower(mix_cased_field) AS mix_cased_field
            FROM yet_more_things
            WHERE yet_more_things.subthing_id = subthings.id
          ) AS yet_more_things
        )
      FROM sub_things
      WHERE sub_things.topmost_thing_id = topmost_things.id
    ) AS sub_things
  )
FROM topmost_things
```

When I run the query used to construct the view the resultset matches my expectation. Is this expected behaviour and I'm clueless, or is this a bug?

Comment: Please start by naming your version of Postgres. And show `mix_case_column` in the actual query. Is it `mix_cased_field`?

Comment: Yes, apologies for mixing the names up, fixed now.  The version of PG used is from 9.6 to 10.

Comment: You speak of *columns*, but your (updated) query only produces nested *keys* in a `jsonb` column. Can you demonstrate your case in a fiddle like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b4aea5a2d682cd0b8deb0c1f415bbd52

Comment: They are columns in the subquery, though, my updates never changed that aspect of the query. The fact that they are aggregated into a jsonb object doesn't seem to make any difference to PG and it will dedupe the column names in the query. I can see if I can repeat the problem in a dbfiddle, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: A `SELECT` is allowed to return multiple columns with identical names (even if some clients do not allow the same). But `CREATE VIEW` cannot allow it, as tables (and views) do not allow duplicate column names at all.

But the expected behavior for the case would be:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "mix_case_column" specified more than once
> ```

Tested in Postgres 11.

Postgres does not automatically rename columns like that. Not to my knowledge at least. There may be some middleware interfering?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the fact that the subselects are aggregated using `jsonb_agg` eliminates the error but not the renaming behaviour? This has been tested on PG 9.6 to 10 and behaviour is the same. I'm not using any custom middleware or ORM.

Comment: To clarify, the "top level" select does not return duplicate column names, but both subselects used within the query do.